# Add project reference , work only before build

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, dll, reference, class-library

i got a winforms application and 2 lib projects

i'm adding project reference to the winform project for both lib projects

with one of the lib projects i got a strange problem.

I'm adding Project reference
In the cs file i'm adding the using statement  and the intellisense find the newly added lib project.
all works good
once i build the winform project / build all i got an error:

Error   5   The type or namespace name 'Common' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I checked the build order and the Common lib project is the first one.. so i dont have any idea why i can't use this assembly

any ideas ?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you marked the classes in your libs as `public`?

Comment: I'm having this same issue with a .NET built ActiveX control (COM visible implementing IObjectSafety.) Still haven't figured out the solution.